# Bijective Functions between Multiple Dimensions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Do bijective functions exist that map from a function of one dimension to a function of another dimension?  For example, does there exist a function $f : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ that is bijective?  If so, would you please provide an example?  If not, how is it possible to prove why this is not possible?

Comment: Yes, because $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Wam, bam! Enjoy the gold badge.

Comment: @Git Gud: I have been enjoying it, thank you. With the exception of two-three times that I was uncertain of my vote, and one time that I misread the question and immediately reopened it.